# Searching for a font that's similar to Lato

Tags: website-design, font-recommendation, sans-serif

I need to find a font just like Lato font that includes a Latin Extended version. I like Lato but it doesn’t include characters from Latin Extended and so I can’t type *ş, ğ* etc.

Here's an example screenshot:

[image]

I’m using this font for my web-site project.

Comment: Hi user15725, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question! Could you please post an image of the Lato typeface you're referring to? This will make it easier for people to help you, even if they don't have the typeface themselves.

Comment: here u're http://p1310.hizliresim.com/1g/1/t5vsq.png these all are Lato font from google fonts

Comment: It don't include 'č' and 'ž' characters.

Comment: This is a similar font - https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Assistant

Answer (score 4):

I found [Open Sans](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Open+Sans) and [Oxygen](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Oxygen) to be similar. Also take a look at [Pt Sans](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/PT+Sans).

Comment: Open Sans work for me. I just had to change "bold" for "600" because _Open Sans bold (700)_ is too much width than _Lato bold (700)_

Answer (score 4):

Lato now supports Latin Extended characters (Aug 2014):

http://www.latofonts.com/lato-free-fonts/

Google Fonts:

https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Lato

Enjoy!

Comment: Looks like the extended is not working. I've tried with Google fonts, and the special characters that should be rendered with the Extended one fallback to other system font such as Arial. Now I've downloaded the original files from Lato Fonts website but at the moment I get only white space instead of the font.

Comment: > Lato now supports Latin Extended characters (Aug 2014): No. It don't include 'čČ' , 'ėĖ', 'ųŲ' characters

Answer (score 1):

How about using 'Open Sans' or 'Source Sans'. I personally like 'Open Sans'

Comment: 'open sans' is not enough low height, this is so much longder than Lato :S but thx

Answer (score 1):

One similar, although not identical, font which does contain those characters is [Scala Sans](https://www.fontfont.com/fonts/scala-sans). It's available for web and desktop, but it certainly isn't free.

[image: Scala Sans example]